# Avro file load and read from Snowflake table

Tags: avro, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am aware that VARIANT data type can be used to load unstructured files, however does this data type support UNION data type of Avro ie - Day 1 Name was record type in avro file and day 2 it is changed to Array. In that case in Hive i will be able to read both records with the help of UNION data type, do snowflake provide same kind of support to read both record and array element from the table?

Regards,
Gopi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the union type in Avro [is supported in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-intro.html#what-is-avro), along with most other complex data types.

The `VARIANT` produced upon read of each separate row will reflect the discovered Avro field data-type, including the true data-type found after evaluating a union-type field.